# InvokeRequired=true but BeginInvoke fails causing freeze

Tags: c#, winforms, begininvoke

C# windows forms VS 2013 OS:Win7

I am having an interesting problem where invokeRequired is true but when I call beginInvoke() it never executes and the window never closes.

However when I remove beingInvoke() altogether the window closes ok.

```
     public void CloseMyForm()
            {
//if I remove this if block altogether including beingInvoke() the window closes ok
                if ( !this.IsDisposed && this.InvokeRequired && this.IsHandleCreated )
                {
                    log("callin begininvoke()"); //this is logged correctly 

                    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { CloseMyForm(); });
                    return;
                }
               log("outside of begin invoke"); //this is never logged
               this.Close();
            }
```

CloseMyForm is called by a separate thread which is created like this at the startup. Please note this is not the main window but a separate window open from the main form.

```
Thread connectThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckWhenToCloseMyForm)); 

    public void CheckWhenToCloseMyForm()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            CallSomeFunc();
            CallSomeFunc1();
            if (allconditionsmet)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                CloseMyForm();
break;

            }        
        }       
    }
```

Comment: What is calling `CloseMyForm` initially?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be calling a method like this from a background thread.

Comment: CloseMyForm is called by a separete thread initially.                                Thread connectThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckWhenTo CloseMyForm)); The CheckWhenToCloseMyForm() has a while(true) loop that calls CloseMyForm after certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 2):

The [`BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) is made available via the base `Control` class.

> Executes a delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's underlying handle was created on

If the [`InvokedRequired`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx) property is actually true, that means "the caller must call an invoke method when making method calls to the control because the caller is on a different thread than the one the control was created on".

It looks like you're incorrectly calling `BeginInvoke`, you should try calling [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

> Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle

```
public void CloseMyForm()
{
    if (!this.IsDisposed && this.InvokeRequired && this.IsHandleCreated)
    {
        log("calling invoke()");
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { CloseMyForm(); });
    }
    else
    {
        log("outside of invoke"); // this is never logged
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Check out [this neat little extension method](https://onlycsharp.wordpress.com/sharpening/extension-methods/) that could help simplify this. With this you could write your close method like this instead.

```
public void CloseMyForm()
{
    this.ThreadSafeInvoke(() => this.Close());
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not help. the window still does not close

Comment: What is calling `CloseMyForm` externally?

Comment: CloseMyForm is called by a separete thread initially. Thread connectThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckWhenTo CloseMyForm)); The CheckWhenToCloseMyForm() has a while(true) loop that calls CloseMyForm after certain conditions are met.

Comment: Abandon all hope, why would you spin up an entirely new thread for that - "Jeffrey Richter's face would be bright red"! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480359/should-i-use-invoke-or-synchronizationcontext-to-update-form-controls-from-anoth or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386576/c-sharp-opening-a-form-then-closing-it-from-another-method

Comment: Its an existing application, I cant really change much,

Comment: yeah, the same form which we are trying to close.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now that you have provided this snippet I understand the issue.

```
Thread connectThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckWhenToCloseMyForm)); 

public void CheckWhenToCloseMyForm()
{
    while (true)
    {
        CallSomeFunc();
        CallSomeFunc1();
        if (allconditionsmet)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            CloseMyForm()
        }        
    }       
}
```

In your `while` loop you need to `break` or `return` after you invoke `CloseMyForm`. That's it...very simple.  You can use either `BeginInvoke` or `Invoke`.

Comment: really sorry, actually I do have a break that I missed when I was posting it. I have edited code to show the break; statement